# Using preview package of hydrated_bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, pubspec.yaml

I want to use the 9.0.0-dev version of the [hydrated_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/hydrated_bloc/versions/9.0.0-dev.3) package.

If I run `pub get` on my pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  hydrated_bloc: ^9.0.0-dev.3
```

I get the message `Latest available version is: 8.1.0`

How can I get the prereleases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the version found on pud.dev.
If you want to use the latest dev package you could point to the github repo instead

```yaml
hydrated_bloc:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/felangel/bloc.git
      ref: master
      path: packages/hydrated_bloc/
```